# Set vue-router messages via axios call

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to fetch my translation messages via an api call to my backend app. In the `then` callback of the `axios` call I'd like to set the messages.

However the issue seems to be that VueRouter is already initialised with the empty translations and is not getting reloaded with the new ones from the `then` callback.

Is there a way for me to achieve this?

I've tried:

```
let messages = {};
window.axios.get(route('api.translation.translations.all'))
    .then(response => {
        messages = {
            [currentLocale]: response.data,
        }
    });
console.log(messages);

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: currentLocale, 
    messages, 
});
```

This doesn't work as `new VueI18n` is called before messages is fully set.

```
window.axios.get(route('api.translation.translations.all'))
    .then(response => {
        messages = {
            [currentLocale]: response.data,
        };
        console.log(messages);
        app.$i18n.setLocaleMessage('en', messages)
    });
```

This also doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I didn't need to specify the locale, as it's the first argument of  `setLocaleMessage`.

```
window.axios.get(route('api.translation.translations.all'))
    .then(response => {
        messages = response.data;

        app.$i18n.setLocaleMessage(currentLocale, messages);
    });
```